# speeding up nested lcm calculation

Tags: optimization, lcm

How can I speed up this calculation. I have tried some of way to reduce computation but nothing works.

```
long long pairsFormLCM( int n ) {
    long long res = 0;
    for( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        for( int j = i; j <= n; j++ )
           if( lcm(i, j) == n ) res++; // lcm means least common multiple
    return res;
}
```

I do not expect any code here. Idea or explanation of solve is required.

```
Expected run time: O(sqrt(N))
```

Comment: **1.** `lcm(i, j) == lcm(j, i)` so that should cut in half. **2.** `i, j` can only be divisors of n, so that should give you another huge boost. **3.** you could probably find an algorithm that doesn't require to check lcm(i,j), but rather generate i,j (not sure, algorithms not my strong point)

Comment: 1.lcm(i, j) == lcm(j, i) is not computed here. because in nested for loop it starts from i.

Comment: sry, saw `j=1`. You are wright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying all integer pairs in `[1,n]` is really overkill. You should factor `n` and count all products of the factors such that the required multiplicity is achieved by at least one of the products. (The `lcm` of two integers is the product of all their prime factors, each taken with the largest multiplicity.)

Example:

For `n=1500=2².3.5³`, the following multiplicities will work:

```
For 2, 5 combinations: (0,2), (1,2), (2,2), (2,1), (2,0)
For 3, 3 combinations: (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)
For 5, 7 combinations: (0,3), (1,3), (2,3), (3,3), (3,2), (3,1), (3,0)
```

In total, `5.3.7 = 105` solutions:

```
(1.1.1,2².3.5³), (2.1.1,2².3.5³), (2².1.1,2².3.5³), (2².1.1,2.3.5³), (2².1.1,1.3.5³),
(1.3.1,2².3.5³), (2.3.1,2².3.5³), (2².3.1,2².3.5³), (2².3.1,2.3.5³), (2².3.1,1.3.5³),
(1.3.1,2².1.5³), (2.3.1,2².1.5³), (2².3.1,2².1.5³), (2².3.1,2.1.5³), (2².3.1,1.1.5³),
(1.1.5,2².3.5³), (2.1.5,2².3.5³), (2².1.5,2².3.5³), (2².1.5,2.3.5³), (2².1.5,1.3.5³),
(1.3.5,2².3.5³), (2.3.5,2².3.5³), (2².3.5,2².3.5³), (2².3.5,2.3.5³), (2².3.5,1.3.5³),
(1.3.5,2².1.5³), (2.3.5,2².1.5³), (2².3.5,2².1.5³), (2².3.5,2.1.5³), (2².3.5,1.1.5³),
(1.1.5²,2².3.5³), (2.1.5²,2².3.5³), (2².1.5²,2².3.5³), (2².1.5²,2.3.5³), (2².1.5²,1.3.5³),
(1.3.5²,2².3.5³), (2.3.5²,2².3.5³), (2².3.5²,2².3.5³), (2².3.5²,2.3.5³), (2².3.5²,1.3.5³),
(1.3.5²,2².1.5³), (2.3.5²,2².1.5³), (2².3.5²,2².1.5³), (2².3.5²,2.1.5³), (2².3.5²,1.1.5³),
(1.1.5³,2².3.5³), (2.1.5³,2².3.5³), (2².1.5³,2².3.5³), (2².1.5³,2.3.5³), (2².1.5³,1.3.5³),
(1.3.5³,2².3.5³), (2.3.5³,2².3.5³), (2².3.5³,2².3.5³), (2².3.5³,2.3.5³), (2².3.5³,1.3.5³),
(1.3.5³,2².1.5³), (2.3.5³,2².1.5³), (2².3.5³,2².1.5³), (2².3.5³,2.1.5³), (2².3.5³,1.1.5³),
(1.1.5³,2².3.5²), (2.1.5³,2².3.5²), (2².1.5³,2².3.5²), (2².1.5³,2.3.5²), (2².1.5³,1.3.5²),
(1.3.5³,2².3.5²), (2.3.5³,2².3.5²), (2².3.5³,2².3.5²), (2².3.5³,2.3.5²), (2².3.5³,1.3.5²),
(1.3.5³,2².1.5²), (2.3.5³,2².1.5²), (2².3.5³,2².1.5²), (2².3.5³,2.1.5²), (2².3.5³,1.1.5²),
(1.1.5³,2².3.5), (2.1.5³,2².3.5), (2².1.5³,2².3.5), (2².1.5³,2.3.5), (2².1.5³,1.3.5),
(1.3.5³,2².3.5), (2.3.5³,2².3.5), (2².3.5³,2².3.5), (2².3.5³,2.3.5), (2².3.5³,1.3.5),
(1.3.5³,2².1.5), (2.3.5³,2².1.5), (2².3.5³,2².1.5), (2².3.5³,2.1.5), (2².3.5³,1.1.5),
(1.1.5³,2².3.1), (2.1.5³,2².3.1), (2².1.5³,2².3.1), (2².1.5³,2.3.1), (2².1.5³,1.3.1),
(1.3.5³,2².3.1), (2.3.5³,2².3.1), (2².3.5³,2².3.1), (2².3.5³,2.3.1), (2².3.5³,1.3.1),
(1.3.5³,2².1.1), (2.3.5³,2².1.1), (2².3.5³,2².1.1), (2².3.5³,2.1.1), (2².3.5³,1.1.1)
```

There is no need to actually compute the numbers, counting them suffices. More generally, the number of solutions is the product of the multiplicities of all factors of `n`, each times two plus one.

Beware that some of the solutions are counted twice, by symmetry. This must be fixed.

Comment: Nice Example, Neat and clean ... :) A big Thanks ... (y)